# Script esta considera o enter como espaço em branco

Tags: javascript, jquery

Fiz um script para retirar espaços em branco de uma string dentro de um TEXTAREA ou INPUT, segue o código logo abaixo:

```
  input = 'input[type="text"]:not(.inputData), textarea';

  $(document).on('blur', input, function(){
    console.log('blur');
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\s\s+/g, ' '));
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''));
  });
```

O problema desse código é que ele considera o enter que eu dou dentro de uma textarea como espaço em branco também e ele deixa tudo na mensa linha quando termino de digitar, exemplo:

Quero que fique assim:

Testando:
 
1- Teste 
2- Teste 
3- Teste

Mas ai o script vai e deixa tudo na mesma linha assim considerando o entre como espaço também, segue o exemplo:

Testando: 1- Teste 2- Teste 3- Teste

Quero que tire os espaços em branco, mas sem considerar o enter como espaço em branco, para continuar dando essa quebra de linha normalmente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o `unicode` do `whitespace` para especificar melhor:

```
$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\u0020+/g, ' '));
```

Exemplo:

```js
input = 'input[type="text"]:not(.inputData), textarea';

$(document).on('blur', input, function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\u0020+/g, ' '));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
```

O problema é que o `\s` considera não só o 'espaço' como `whitespace`, e acaba interpretando as quebras de linha também. Usando o `unicode` ele só vai considerar espaços da barra de espaço.

Você pode ler mais sobre o `\s` [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_whitespace.asp).

Comment: Não iria ser fácil descobrir isso. Obrigado ! vou dar uma lida sobre isso.